# Adding and removing class with ngClick

Tags: angularjs

I'm playing around with this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EY3i8OnvdlQuyq2WnAJI?p=preview)

"Special stuff" button adds a class and so I would like "don't click" button to remove that class. Could someone help me out here? Thx

Comment: you mean you want to hide the "don't click" button when the "special stuff" button is clicked? Only for that item?

Comment: @AndrewKuklewicz I would like to remove the class. "Special stuff" button adds a class and so I would like "don't click" button to remove that class. Sorry, I should've been more clear and explicit when naming the buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code:

```
scope.itemUnclicked = function ($index) {
    console.log($index);
    $scope.selectedIndex != $index;
}
```

Umm, did you mean:

```
scope.itemUnclicked = function ($index) {
    console.log($index);
    $scope.selectedIndex = -1;
}
```

`$scope.selectedIndex != $index` will just make a comparison and then throw the result away without changing anything.